# Overlapping 2D shapes in erlang

Tags: erlang

Hello following my question before i have done my research and came up with this,

Basically i am trying to find whether a circle,circle...rectangle,rectangle or circle,rectangle overlap

Mathematically i have my 3 cases as pseudocoded algorithms,what i need help with is to implement this in erlang but i will only ask for circle,circle since i can just figure out the rest syntaxically.

```
perim({circle, {X,Y}, R}) -> 
math:pi()*(R * 2);
perim({rectangle, {X,Y}, H, W})-> 
  (H + W) * 2.

overlap({_,{_,_},_,_},{_,{_,_},_,_}) ->
overlapping({_,{_,_},_,_},{_,{_,_},_,_}).


%overlap cases

%Circle,Circle
overlapping({circle, {X,Y}, R},{circle2, {X2,Y2}, R2}) ->
   circle1 = {{X,Y},R},
   circle2 = {{X2,Y2},R2},
   case (math:sqrt(abs(X)-abs(X2)) + math:sqrt(abs(Y)-abs(Y2))) < math:sqrt(abs(R)+abs(R2)) of
           true -> true;
           false -> false
    end.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is all i have come with up to now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- Since you're representing circles as tuples of the form `{circle, {X,Y}, R}`, both arguments to the `overlapping` function should say `circle`.  If you put `circle2` for the second argument, it won't match your circle tuples, and you'll get a `function_clause` error.
- Since you're already matching out the variables `X`, `Y`, `R`, `X2`, `Y2` and `R2` in the function head, there is no need for the two lines below that.  (In fact, those will always fail, since any word starting with a lower-case letter is an atom, and you're trying to match an atom against a tuple: that will give you a `badmatch` error.)

So that would be:

```
overlapping({circle, {X,Y}, R},{circle, {X2,Y2}, R2}) ->
   case (math:sqrt(abs(X)-abs(X2)) + math:sqrt(abs(Y)-abs(Y2))) < math:sqrt(abs(R)+abs(R2)) of
           true -> true;
           false -> false
    end.
```

Also, since all that `case` is doing is checking for `true` or `false` and returning the same value, you can simplify your code by removing it:

```
overlapping({circle, {X,Y}, R},{circle, {X2,Y2}, R2}) ->
   (math:sqrt(abs(X)-abs(X2)) + math:sqrt(abs(Y)-abs(Y2))) < math:sqrt(abs(R)+abs(R2)).
```

---

To learn more about pattern matching, you might find [this chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) from "Learn You Some Erlang" useful.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark under the score indicator.

Comment: quick question. can i have this
overlapping()
  case of
   end.
overlapping()
case of
end.
i mean pattern match with cases

Answer (score 0):

Can't properly format your code snippet in the comment. Try this (with ';' after each case statement):

```
overlap({{circle,{X,Y},R},{rectangle,{X2,Y2},H,W}}) ->
   X_Axis = X - X2,
   Y_Axis = Y - Y2,
      case abs(X_Axis) >= (0.5*abs(W) + R) orelse abs(Y_Axis) >= (0.5*abs(H) + R) of
        true -> ((X == X2) andalso (Y-Y2));
        true -> ((abs(X_Axis) < 0.5*W) andalso (abs(Y_Axis) < (0.5*H + R)));
        true -> ((abs(X_Axis) < 0.5*W + R) andalso (abs(Y_Axis) < 0.5*H));
        false -> false  
      end.
```

Comment: syntax error before '>='  -->   case abs(X_Axis) >= (0.5*abs(W) + R) or abs(Y_Axis) >= (0.5*abs(H) + R) of

Comment: Should be `orelse` instead of `or`. Corrected, try now.